# Ubuntu 17.04 Server - adding ssd to existing LVM

Tags: server, ssd, 17.04, lvm

I just installed Ubuntu 17.04 server on a Samsung EVO 960 500GB M.2 drive..  I also installed a 1TB Crucial SSD drive..  I want this drive to be in my existing LVM and move /home to it..

Been googling this subject to death and not able to figure it out..  I did the pvcreate to mark it as an LVM physical volume but that is as far as I got.. Mostly everything I found on google was to move to a new ssd not adding one..

So far:

```
sudo lvmdiskscan
  /dev/nvme0n1        [     465.76 GiB]
  /dev/srv3-vg/root   [     401.30 GiB]
  /dev/nvme0n1p1      [     512.00 MiB]
  /dev/sda1           [     978.09 GiB] LVM physical volume
  /dev/srv3-vg/swap_1 [      63.95 GiB]
  /dev/nvme0n1p2      [     465.26 GiB] LVM physical volume
  1 disk
  3 partitions
  0 LVM physical volume whole disks
  2 LVM physical volumes

 sudo lvs
  LV     VG      Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  root   srv3-vg -wi-ao---- 401.30g                                             
  swap_1 srv3-vg -wi-ao----  63.95g

sudo pvs
  PV             VG      Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/nvme0n1p2 srv3-vg lvm2 a--  465.26g      0
  /dev/sda1              lvm2 ---  978.09g 978.09g



sudo vgs
  VG      #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  srv3-vg   1   2   0 wz--n- 465.26g    0
```

Since the ssd is on a sata port and not as fast as the M.2, I wanted to use this for home directories..  Can someone help me out on how to do this?

Comment: When you add the new SSD to the same LV group, and create a LV for `/home` in the group, you cannot decide which data are stored on which physical volume. So, if you want to use LVM for the new disk, you will have to create a new LV group (`man vgcreate`) and then a new LV (`man lvcreate`) for '/home`.  There are lots of tutorials for that, but the manpages should be sufficient.

Comment: I ended up just creating an ext4 drive, renaming /home to /home_bak, mkdir /home, chmod 755 /home, and manually adding it to fstab mounting it to /home.. then copied over folders and files from /home_bak to the new /home.